# Using custom SharePoint rendering templates

Tags: sharepoint, forms, moss

In MOSS 2007 (SharePoint), is there any way to access the current SPField from inside a ListFieldIterator rendering template?

Answer (score 1):

A list field iterator is not a rendering template - it is a class.

If you create a custom field iterator (which inherits ListFieldIterator) and add that to a custom rendering template you should be able to get at any field on the item.  I've used this approach to show / hide fields for ListItems where the IsFieldExcluded method is overridden